# Where does ZSH loads the env variable from

Tags: zsh

I am trying to change the ruby version with rbenv, it seems that there is an env variable

```
RBENV_VERSION=3.0.1
```

I cannot find where does this comes from, there is no declaration on `.zshrc` file.
On the .szhenv file I have the following

```
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Is there any other file that could define this env variable?

Answer (score 1):

It's most likely the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` line. That runs `rbenv init -` and then runs the output as shell commands.

If that doesn't help, you can add `setopt xtrace` to the start of your .zshenv. This will dump every command the shell runs to stderr, with file names and line numbers. You can then do `zsh -il 2>trace.log` and search trace.log for RBENV_VERSION.

From the [rbenv github page](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#rbenv-shell), it looks like you can use `rbenv shell <version>` to set the version for a shell session, which sets `$RBENV_VERSION`.